# RSS parser interacting with another software using Bash or Python

Tags: linux, bash, python, rss, raspbian

I'm trying to create a program or script  (let's call it `Worker`) running in Linux environment (desirable would be Raspbian or Debian), that collects links from RSS feeds and sends them to another 2 programs for processing.

Here are particular steps that `Worker` should do:

1. Parse multiple RSS feeds from a text document that are separated by new line

   ```
   https://example.com/feed.xml?id1 nsfw
   https://example.com/feed.xml?id2
   https://example.com/feed.xml?id3
   [...]
   https://example.com/feed.xml?id9`
   ```
2. Extract links from each feed
3. Delete links with particular keywords in the `<title>` element. Keywords are set for each feed in the text document separated from respective link by space like that:

   ```
   https://example.com/feed.xml?id1 nsfw
   ```

   and if not set - no removal needed.
4. Sort resulting links by date/time based on `<published>` element. Example:

   ```
   <published>2018-07-27T01:02:03+00:00</published>
   ```
5. Send the newest link to a `handler` program (it's just an external program that already exists)

   ```
   handler https://received-from-RSS.com/abc
   ```
6. Mark the sent link as `watched` (preferably to do it in memory only, since that It should run on Raspberry Pi and I would like to reduce SD card usage)
7. Collect a response from `handler` program which should contain another link, and pass the link gotten from `handler` to a `player` program

   ```
   player https://received-from-Handler.com/xyz
   ```
8. Wait untill the `player` finishes playing and closes. Then send chronologically next (and not yet marked `watched`) link to the `handler`

   And we are repeating stages 5 to 8.
9. Each 30 minutes `Worker` should update links from RSS feeds, e.g. repeat stages 1 to 9, keeping `watched` links in memory and not sending them to the `handler`.

I feel that this functionality can be implemented in Bash or Python. I have no programming experience, but desperately need the `Worker` up and running.
So I would be grateful if you advice me some specific learning materials or code examples that would help me to write this particular program. I'm not asking to write it for me, I will appreciate your help with any separate step. I just need some directions

I will post the result here once I finish.

Comment: What research have you done on your own to attempt to solve this? Requests for learning material recommendations are off-topic on this stack; please see [What topics can I ask about?](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: writing answer..

Comment: feedparser - RSS feed parser library in Python. datetime - Python  standard library for sort by date. [open](https://github.com/rsmith-nl/scripts/blob/master/open.py)- for opening external programs. [schedule](https://github.com/dbader/schedule) - for periodic jobs. However I would prefer to do it using bash, but I have no idea on how to parse RSS with it.

Comment: Shell languages aren't generally going to be the right tool for a project like this, although it's _possible_ that you could do it with PowerShell. In any case, once you have some attempt at doing it yourself, and can identify specific problems that you are having, a well-written and detailed question on [so] may be more appropriate than asking here.